# XSL-FO: is XSL-FO dead technology and only used by niche companies?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I wanted to convert some xml to a magazine like pdf document. A lot like what LaTeX allows you to do however i was not able to find any new books or online tutorials on the subject. Is it worth investing in using this technology or not?

Also, I looked at the Apache XSL-FO project and their last release was in august 2008.

p.s. commercial packages are not an option :(

Comment: Maybe the last released was in August 2008 because they achieved all their goals, and they don't have a need for further development.

Comment: the answers to this question suggest that XSL-FO is alive and kicking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052718/xsl-fo-compared-to-classical-technologies

Comment: @Colin: Interesting that the OP in your linked question is asking if *older* technologies might be better. :)

Comment: May be of interest - seems like Apache FOP 1.0 was released July 12, 2010. It implements "a large subset of the XSL-FO Version 1.1 W3C Recommendation". More details at http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the only reason for the less availability of XSL-FO processors is due to the fact that it's formatting options are pretty large and quite complex too..

Since the amount of complexity involved, no one wants to sweat so much and make it open sourced. I heard there were quite good number of cool commercial processors available for XSL-FO. Even Apache FOP is a nice one to generate pdfs out of it.

Though i haven't used LuaTex, i found XSL-FO is a fun to work. Also it uses just XML to generate pdfs. If you ask me i will tell, it's simple yet powerful. And also i don't want it to die either.. :)

Answer (score 6):

There is currently no free XSL-FO formatter besides FOP and a few others, which are (IMHO) not really usable. But that does not mean, XSL-FO is dead or so, it is used heavily in technical documentation.

Creating a full featured, standard compliant XSL-FO formatter is pretty hard, and FOP is not there yet. I'd guess that they are bitten by the pure complexity of the standard.

My company is currently creating another XSL-FO formatter with focus on high typographical output based on [LuaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX), so I know I bit of this area. It is not decided yet whether this will be open sourced or not. (Sorry that I can't help you there).

So my answer is: go with Apache FOP. Even if the last change is some time ago, it is pretty usable at this point. And XSL-FO is far from being dead. If you can afford it, use a decent XML Editor (such as [OxygenXML](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)) for editing, it makes editing XSL stylesheets fun. (I don't get any money by mentioning this.)

Comment: NFop is a .NET alternative, ported from Fop. Seems it doesn't support  floats at time of writing - which might not change, their last release was around two years ago.

Answer (score 3):

No, neither dead nor niche.

The question in 2010 pointed to the previous FOP release being in 2008.  As of 2018, FOP has made a release every year between 2015 and 2018 (see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/news.html).  If you were to also look at commercial formatters, Antenna House makes a maintenance release roughly every 45 days (see https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/news-events/).

https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/formatter/ currently has links to samples of a car manual, an annual report, and a tax form.  Train tickets in Germany are generated using XSL-FO.  I'm sometimes surprised how widely it is used.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new in this area you can also use a visual design tool. I found the XSL-FO Designer  from [Ecrion](http://www.ecrion.com/) to be good for both programmers familiar with XSLT and XSL-FO and old ladies that need to make changes to the templates (we are deploying a desktop solution based on XSL-FO that replaces an older proprietary solution and the ladies can make small changes to the document templates :) ).

FOP is indeed not maintained anymore, but the commercial vendors are doing a great job at providing faster and quite affordable solutions and the set of features is growing with every release (a 2.0 draft of the [XSL-FO specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req/) is now in the works!).

Answer (score 2):

### XSL-FO is officially dying

On Sat, 2013-11-02, [Liam R. E. Quin](http://www.w3.org/People/Quin/) [wrote](http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/201311/msg00012.html):
*"We have closed the Working Group because not enough people were taking part"*, W3C XML Activity Lead, about the failure of [XSL-FO 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/) continuity.

The last update for the Working Draft was in January 2012, and now confirmed: **W3C stop developing XSL-2**.

Why?  It will be replaced by [CSS3-page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page), see  [Use of XSL-FO, CSS3 instead of CSS2 to create Paginated documents like PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10641667/287948)

PS: open-source projects dyed early. The [Apache XSL-FO project](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) last release, for instance, was in August 2008, then in 2012 (thanks @mzjn for updating!), with (FOP v1.1) ~100 fixded bugs.

### -----

Edit: in Jun 2015 *XSL-FO 2.0* remains as "W3C Working Draft 17" (of January 2012). But we need to correct PS about Apache (thanks @mzjn!), that was released as [Apache FOP 2.0](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/). Also softwares like [3B2](http://gpsl.co/can-you-help-me/products-and-services/3b2/) has been maintained.

Comment: The latest release of Apache FOP was in **October 2012**; http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/changes_1.1.html, http://markmail.org/message/7jardmwgfpbdwwma.

Comment: FOP 2.0 was released on June 3, 2015. See http://markmail.org/message/s5jox57bbhtkd5o6.

Answer (score 2):

While XSL-FO processor are being developed, you have to consider how complex your formatting requirements are and how well any processor meets your need.  FOP certainly does not all the features you'll find in the Antenna House product but probably does most of what you want for a basic magazine layout.

As for the complexity of FO, it certainly covers a broad spectrum of formatting needs, but the basics are not so difficult to pick up with a little practice.  If you have a fair working knowledge of XSL and any experience with CSS, you should pick up FO basics easily.  I've picked up what I know by just Googling and reading and building from simple to complex.

Answer (score 1):

Apache FOP is maintained and has only recently reached version 1.0 but don't be fooled this isn't the first release as is the culmination of many years of work. There was a period several years ago where it looked as if the project was dead but they were working on major changes at the time. Since then there have been releases on a regular basis with each one improving the compatibility and functionality.

Also and if you do have problems (I mean bugs or technical issues with the renderer not questions about FO) I've found the FOP team really helpful and have always given quick responses.